# unable to add onChange props in react-select's multi selection in ReactJS Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-select

In ReactJS, I'm using [react-select](https://react-select.com/typescript) to implement the multi-select dropdown field, like below but when I try to add `onchange` props, I'm getting this issue

```
ERROR in src/components/Pages/CreatePage.tsx:196:25
TS2322: Type '(selected: Vehicle[] | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(newValue: MultiValue<Vehicle>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<Vehicle>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'selected' and 'newValue' are incompatible.
    The type 'MultiValue<Vehicle>' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Vehicle[]'.
    194 |                         isClearable={true}
    195 |                         backspaceRemovesValue={true}
  > 196 |                         onChange={handleSelectChange}
        |                         ^^^^^^^^
    197 |                         
    198 |                     />
```

> Code I tried

```
    import Select from 'react-select';


    interface Vehicle {
       id: number;
       make: string;
       model: string;
       year: number;
   }

   const vehicles: Vehicle[] = [{
       id: 1,
       make: 'Ford',
       model: 'Fiesta',
       year: 2003,
   }, {
       id: 7,
       make: 'Audi',
       model: 'A4',
       year: 2009,
   }, ];

   const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
       const [Vehicles, setVehicles] = useState < Vehicle[] > ([]);
       const handleSelectChange = (selected: Vehicle[] | null) => {
           if (selected) {
               setVehicles(selected);
           }
       };
       return (
                     <Select
                        isMulti
                        getOptionLabel={(vehicle: Vehicle) => vehicle.model}
                        getOptionValue={(vehicle: Vehicle) => vehicle.model}
                        options={vehicles}
                        isClearable={true}
                        backspaceRemovesValue={true}
                        // onChange={handleSelectChange}     
                    />);
   };

   export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: The TypeError pretty clearly tells you what the signature of the `onChange` function needs to be

Comment: The error message is `The type 'MultiValue<Vehicle>' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Vehicle[]'.` so have you tried using `ReadonlyArray<Vehicle>` instead?

Comment: `export type MultiValue<Option> = readonly Option[];` - [Source](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/a465818786afd4857c9155bef1e9aa2fe3356097/packages/react-select/src/types.ts#L16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*react-select@^5.7.2*

You have two choices:

1. Use `OnChangeValue<Option, true>`.

Let's check the this type:

```
export declare type SingleValue<Option> = Option | null;
export declare type MultiValue<Option> = readonly Option[];

//...
export declare type OnChangeValue<Option, IsMulti extends boolean> = IsMulti extends true ? MultiValue<Option> : SingleValue<Option>;
```

It uses TS [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), if `isMulti` is `true`, then the final type is `readonly Option[]`.

This mentioned at documentation:

`IsMulti extends boolean = false`

> This type is `false` for single-selects and is `true` for multi-selects. It defaults to false for the exported components because TypeScript isn't smart enough to figure out that it should be false if the `isMulti` prop is not specified, but on other exported interfaces it defaults to boolean so that it handles both single-select and multi-select values. This generic is primarily used to determine the type of the first argument passed to onChange which will be `Option | null` if `IsMulti` is `false` and will be `readonly Option[]` if `IsMulti` is `true`.

```
const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const [Vehicles, setVehicles] = React.useState<readonly Vehicle[]>([]);
    const handleSelectChange = (selected: OnChangeValue<Vehicle, true>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<Vehicle>) => {
        console.log(selected, actionMeta);
        if (selected) {
            setVehicles(selected);
        }
    };
    return (
        <Select
            isMulti
            getOptionLabel={(vehicle: Vehicle) => vehicle.model}
            getOptionValue={(vehicle: Vehicle) => vehicle.model}
            options={vehicles}
            isClearable={true}
            backspaceRemovesValue={true}
            onChange={handleSelectChange}
        />
    );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76650862-js4dym?file=/src/App.tsx:359-931)

2. Use `read-only Option[]` mentioned at [official documentation](https://react-select.com/typescript#onchange)

Besides, we have to declare the type for `state` as readonly.

```
const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const [Vehicles, setVehicles] = React.useState<readonly Vehicle[]>([]);
    const handleSelectChange = (selected: readonly Vehicle[], actionMeta: ActionMeta<Vehicle>) => {
        console.log(selected, actionMeta);
        if (selected) {
            setVehicles(selected);
        }
    };
    return (
        <Select
            isMulti
            getOptionLabel={(vehicle: Vehicle) => vehicle.model}
            getOptionValue={(vehicle: Vehicle) => vehicle.model}
            options={vehicles}
            isClearable={true}
            backspaceRemovesValue={true}
            onChange={handleSelectChange}
        />
    );
};
```